# Из за чего не получается создавать объект enum внутри самого enum -а?

Tags: java, enum, instance

```
enum  EnumClass{
    ENUM_CLASS1, ENUM_CLASS2, ENUM_CLASS3;
    EnumClass enumClass = new EnumClass(); //не получается
}
```

Логически понятно, что смысла нет. Также понятно, почему вне enum-а невозможно создать экземпляр, так как конструктор enum является private. Но внутри enum-а почему не удается создавать экземпляр? private как бы предполагает что в других местах нельзя создавать объекты, но внутри самого enum? Тут уже не понятно.

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример не имеет смысла, как вы сами и сказали. Расскажите что вы хотите сделать, из вопроса это совершенно не ясно. Предположу, что вы хотите сделать что-то в этом духе:

```
enum Test {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);

    private int t;
    Test (int t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public int getT(){
        return t;
    }
}
```

Тут создается класс Test extends Enum, и три объекта этого класса. Внутри блока enum используется другой синтаксис конструктора. Вместо

new Test("ONE", 0, 1) //параметры name, ordinal  и t

достаточно написать ONE(1) //name есть, t есть, ordinal счиатется без вашего участия

Так что в вашем примере EnumClass enumClass = new EnumClass() не имеет смысла не потому, что вы не можете создать элемент перечисление, а потому что 1)в блоке такое действие делается другим синтаксисом 2) элемент Enum имеет минимум 2 параметра в конструкторе, а вы хотите создать элемент без них

Comment: Просто интересно знать почему не удается создать обьект enum внутри  enum, если конструктор enum является private. В обычных классах private дает возможность создавать обьект данного класса внутри данного класса. В enum происходит ошибка. Интересно знать "почему?". Ну на основе чего появляется ошибка?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan а Enum вообще через new разве можно создавать?

Comment: Нет, это абстрактный класс. Но в чем связь? спрашиваю на основе этого утверждения "When you define an enumeration, it implicitly inherits from java.lang.Enum.
Internally, enumerations are converted to classes. Further, enumeration constants
are instances of the enumeration class for which the constant is declared as a
member."

Comment: Все еще не ясно что вам не понятно. Когда вы обявляете enum Test { ONE, TWO} вы создаете 2 объекта класса Test extends Enum<Test>, которые сохраняются в статических методах класса Enum. То есть статическая часть Enum - контейнер, объекты классов наследованных от Enum, то есть нестатической части Enum - содержимое для контейнера. Внутри блока enum вы можете создавать объекты класса Test extends Enum<Test>, просто синтаксис другой для удобства. Вместо new Test("ONE", 0) вы просто пишете ONE, имя уходит в переменную name, ordinal сам вычисляется

Comment: Если есть "расширенный" конструктор, то вместо new Test("ONE", 0, 27) вы пишете ONE(27). Имя есть. Параметр есть. ordinal посчитается без вас. Так что ваш вопрос сводится к тому, что вы не восприняли ONE(1) к конструктор с другим синтаксисом

Comment: Дополнил ответ, а то чет много вышло текста

Comment: Минутку, откуда взялся t, если в абстрактном классе Enum конструктор обьявлен следующим образом:   protected Enum(String name, int ordinal) ?

Comment: Что касается остальной части всего что вы написали - мне это известно, и на практике попробовал и увидел что вместо   EnumClass enumClass = new EnumClass();  если объявить EnumClass enumClass = new EnumClass("",4); или даже если условно будем экспериментировать на основе  вашего утверждения, что " ordinal считается без вашего участия"  - в смысле напишем так EnumClass enumClass = new EnumClass(""); то таки создать экземпляр никак не удастся.

Comment: пока единственная версия, которая мне кажется правдоподобной это - отсутствие возможности создания экземпляра традиционным способом, в смысле через new + конструктор заблокирован на уровне компилятора. Просто видит что вместо class написан enum - значит нельзя дать программисту создавать объекты через new+конструктор.  Но правильно ли я заметил? Также: А это вся ли причина из за которого не удается  создавать объекты вручную традиционным способом?

Comment: Так как приватность конструктора обьясняет только отсутствие возможности создания обьектов в других классах, но внутри самого enum, по идее это не может быть мешающим фактором, следовательно тут задействованы иные мешающие факторы.

Comment: Еще раз. Вы не можете вызывать конструктор привычным методом внутри блока enum. Никак. Никогда. Он заменен на другую синтаксическую конструкцию. Вместо new Test("ONE",0) вы просто пишете ONE; javac сам поймет что тут нужно сделать вызывать конструктор, и из того что вы написали он может получить все нужные для конструктора параметры. Так что вы создаете объекты классы класса EnumClass, просто конструктор вызывается по-другому

Comment: Следовательно мое замечание выше - оправдала себя. Спасибо за подтверждение.